# Add check option after view has been created

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I have a `VIEW` created. I am trying to figure out how to add a `CHECK` option.
So is there a way to `ALTER` a `VIEW` and add a `WITH CHECK OPTION`?
Or the only way is to `DROP` the `VIEW` and re-create it?

Tried:
`ALTER VIEW my_view ADD WITH CHECK OPTION` did not work

Comment: Why vote to close?Isn't it specific question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an ALTER VIEW statement, but you'll need to re-input your view contents. So if you created a view as:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
SELECT * FROM MyTable;
```

and you want to add a CHECK OPTION you would use

```
ALTER VIEW MyView AS
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

Comment: So what is the difference with `DROP`ing the view and recreating then?

Comment: Not a lot, but you don't have drop it, so there will not be that short space of time where it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` statement.

First creating a view first:

`CREATE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT * FROM my_table;`

Second adding `WITH CHECK OPTION` into the existing view;

`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT * FROM my_table
WITH CHECK OPTION;`

I hope it helps.